# Having problems with C# inside of my Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code:

```
        string init = "yes";
        string html = "";
        foreach (var item in v.Details) {
               if (item.Substring(0, 1) != " ")
               {
                   if (init != "yes")
                   {
                       html += "</ul>";

                   }
                   html += "<p>" + item + "</p><ul>";
               }
               else
               {
                   html += "<li>" + item.Substring(1) + "</li>";
               }
           }
```

The code is in my MVC controller and it creates a string called html. The thing is I don't think it should be in the controller. I tried to put this into the view and ended up with a huge mess that doesn't seem to work. Seems I am not very good at coding C within a razor view. I just saw a lot of syntax type errors and confusion between what's C and what's HTML.

Can anyone suggest how I could make this code work within a view. Here's what I used to have:

```
        <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Details)
        {
            <li>@item</li>
        } 
        </ul>
```

This worked but as you can see I now need more processing. Would it be better to take this out of the view and if so how could I do this. I'm really hoping for a view solution but I am confused about where the put the @'s and where to put the brackets.

Any experts at coding C inside or Razor out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code is in my MVC controller and it creates a string called html.
>   The thing is I don't think it should be in the controller

You are correct. It shouldn't be in the view neither due to the absolute mess it would create. I think this code is better suited in a custom HTML helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString FormatDetails(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, IEnumerable<string> details)
    {
        var init = "yes";
        var html = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in details)
        {
            if (item.Substring(0, 1) != " ")
            {
                if (init != "yes")
                {
                    html.Append("</ul>");
                }
                html.AppendFormat("<p>{0}</p><ul>", htmlHelper.Encode(item));
            }
            else
            {
                html.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", htmlHelper.Encode(item.Substring(1)));
            }
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
    }
}
```

which you would invoke in your view:

```
@Html.FormatDetails(Model.Details)
```

Remark: there seems to be something wrong with the `init` variable. You are setting its value to `yes` initially but you never modify it later.

Comment: Yes, you'd expect the line that says `if (init != "yes")` to be something like `if (html != "")` instead.

Comment: Thanks Darin, Actually I did correct this later but forgot to post. Glad to hear that you don't think it should be in the view. I did try it there but it looked very messy and every other words seemed to show some syntax problem. Wish they would do something to make the syntax checks in the views a bit better.